# update scope variable on submit and update view in angular js

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm creating my first web app in angularjs and can't get the page to update with new values once the user submits text/numbers in an input box.

I'm using Java8, MongoDB, angularJS and twitter bootstrap

```
HTML:

<td>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="enter bugnumber" data-ng-model="auditdata.newbugnumber"> 

  <h4>Bug Numbers</h4>

  <a href="{{bugLink(a)}}" data-ng-repeat="a in parseBug(auditdata.bugnumber) track by $index">{{a}}</a>

</td>

<td>
  <button type="submit" data-ng-click="add(auditdata)" class="btn btn-danger" >Save</button>
</td>
```

In the HTML above i take input from user in `ng-model=auditadata.newbugnumber` but on server side it sill gets update in the `bugnumber` filed. The `newbugnumber` field is acting like a temp variable which is just used to send the new data to the server. The reason for using the temp variable is to avoid two way binding in angularjs.

I tried using $apply(), $watch and digest in the JS below but can't get the value to be updated in the view. The only way the data gets update in view is when i reload the page which is not an option

```
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$route) {

$scope.isCollapsed = true; 


$http.get('/api/v1/result').success(function (data) {
    $scope.audit = data;   

}).error(function (data, status) {
    console.log('Error ' + data);
})


$scope.add= function(bugInfo) {

     $http.post('/api/v1/result/updateBug', bugInfo).success(function (data) {
             bugInfo.newbugnumber='';
             console.log('audit data updated');

         }).error(function (data, status) {
             console.log('Error ' + data);
         }
   };   
});
```

Update function on server side

```
public void updateAuditData(String body) {

        Result updateAudit = new Gson().fromJson(body, Result.class);
        audit.update(
                new BasicDBObject("_id", new ObjectId(updateAudit.getId())),
                new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject().append("bugnumber",
                        updateAudit.getNewbugnumber())));
    }
```

how bugnumber filed in collection looks like

```
> db.audit.find({"_id" : ObjectId("5696e2cee4b05e970b5a0a68")})
{
        "bugnumber" : [
                "789000",
                "1212"
        ]
}
```

Comment: Please provide a plunker, codepen or jsfiddle to make your question more verifiable

Comment: Could you just call $http.get() from your $http.post() onsuccess function?

Comment: @sjokkogutten I did call $http.get() after post and it works as expected but wasn't sure if that was the right approach. I thing i noticed on $http angularjs documentation page was that `success` method was depreciated and use `then` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, do the following:

Place all your $http handling i a service or factory. This is good practice and makes reuse and testing easier

```
app.factory('AuditService', function($http) {
  var get = function() {
    return $http.get("/api/...") // returns a promise
  };

  var add = function() {
    return $http.post("/api/...") // returns a promise
  };

  return {
    get: get,
    add: add
  }
});
```

And then in your controller

```
// note the import of AuditService
app.controller('listCtrl', function ($scope, $http,$route, AuditService) { 

// other code here


// If insert is successful, then update $scope by calling the newly updated collection. 
// (this is chaining the events using then())
$scope.add = function(bugInfo) {
  AuditService.add().then(
    function(){ // successcallback
      AuditService.get().then(
        function(data){ // success
          $scope.audit = data; 
        },
        function(){ // error
          console.log('error reading data ' + error)
        })
    },
    function(error){ // errorcallback
      console.log('error inserting data ' + error)
    })  
});
```

The same approach can be applied to all CRUD operations